# Unable to display UL list items inline

Tags: html-lists

A simple one I realize, but I'm struggling to get the list items to display inline. any help much appreciated.

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="col-1">
    <h1>Some text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="#">work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">github</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">facebook</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Make code into a functional snippet.

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, but is `<style>li { display: inline }</style>` what you are looking for?